# trying to get vim to work with python

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, code-completion

Im trying to get code completion for python in vim 7.3. When I install vim I use this configuration:

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/vim73 --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=/home/etobkru/Python3/lib/python3.1/config 
make && make install
```

I copy this file:
http://vim.cybermirror.org/runtime/autoload/python3complete.vim
in to the `~/vim73/share/vim/vim73/autoload/` directory and in this file:
`./share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/python.vim` I change

```
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

to

```
setlocal omnifunc=python3complete#Complete.
```

But when I press `<c-x, c-o>` I get an error message:

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python3
E117: Unknown function: python3complete#Complete
```

and if I write `:python3` I get

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

Comment: can you verify by typing :version that the vi you are using has been compiled with python3. Maybe it's different from the one you compiled.

Comment: like mb14 said, can you verify that you are using the correct vim? If you start by typing 'vim' in the terminal, try 'which vim' to see its path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your vim version and on how the OS provides Python and Python3, whether python and python3 are supported both. Else if compiled in at all, then the Python version you first use will be activated.

Check out the following thread and the one linked from there:
[Vim 7.3: Python3 support](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg10741.html)

Answer (score 2):

Delete any autocompletion attempts and forget about your problems, install neocomplcache [(script site)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620)

I had the exact same problem you had and this script solved all my autocompletion needs, its really feature rich and you won't notice its there until you need it.